# How to merge pandas dataframes but only certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to pandas dataframes imported from excel:

```
Position   Sample   Measurement Type   Measurement
 1           1         A                   7.8
 1           1         A                   9.2
 2           2         A                   9.3
 2           2         A                   9.5
 3           1         B                   8.2
 3           1         B                   8.0
```

and

```
Position   Sample     Unique_ID    Other Column 
 1           1         ID_1            aaa
 2           2         ID_2            bbb
 3           1         ID_3            ccc
```

I would like to combine them this way:

```
Position   Sample   Measurement Type   Measurement  Unique_ID
 1           1         A                   7.8        ID_1     
 1           1         A                   9.2        ID_1     
 2           2         A                   9.3        ID_2
 2           2         A                   9.5        ID_2
 3           1         B                   8.2        ID_3
 3           1         B                   8.0        ID_3
```

How can I get the result without the 'Other Column' merging as well?

Doing

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Position', 'Sample'])
```

Works if I then delete the 'Other Column' but it there a way to specify I only want to merge 'Unique_ID' or a list of columns I want to merge.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
df1.merge(df2[["Position", "Sample", "Unique_ID"]], on=['Position', 'Sample'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
# df1 is the first dataframe you've posted (content to merge into)
# df2 is the second dataframe you've posted (content to merge from)
pd.merge(df1, df2["Sample", "Unique ID"]], on="Sample", how="left")
```